# Department Top Three Salary

Tags: mysql

Original questions from leetcode:

```
The Employee table holds all employees. Every employee has an Id, and there is also 
a column for the department Id.

+----+-------+--------+--------------+
| Id | Name  | Salary | DepartmentId |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
| 1  | Joe   | 70000  | 1            |
| 2  | Henry | 80000  | 2            |
| 3  | Sam   | 60000  | 2            |
| 4  | Max   | 90000  | 1            |
| 5  | Janet | 69000  | 1            |
| 6  | Randy | 85000  | 1            |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
The Department table holds all departments of the company.

+----+----------+
| Id | Name     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | IT       |
| 2  | Sales    |
+----+----------+
Write a SQL query to find employees who earn the top three salaries in each of the department. For the above tables, your SQL query should return the following rows.

+------------+----------+--------+
| Department | Employee | Salary |
+------------+----------+--------+
| IT         | Max      | 90000  |
| IT         | Randy    | 85000  |
| IT         | Joe      | 70000  |
| Sales      | Henry    | 80000  |
| Sales      | Sam      | 60000  |
+------------+----------+--------+
```

And I learned one solution online, by doing a self join and then join with the department table.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT d.Name AS Department, e.Name AS Employee, e.Salary
FROM (SELECT e1.Name, e1.Salary, e1.DepartmentId FROM Employee e1 
JOIN Employee e2 WHERE e1.DepartmentId = e2.DepartmentId AND e1.Salary <= e2.Salary 
GROUP BY e1.DepartmentId HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(e2.Salary)) <= 3) e
JOIN Department d
ON e.DepartmentId = d.Id
ORDER BY d.Name, e.Salary DESC
```

And I do not get the correct result:

```
Output:
{"headers": ["Department", "Employee", "Salary"], "values": [["IT", "Joe", 60000]]}
Expected:
{"headers": ["Department", "Employee", "Salary"], "values": [["IT", "Joe", 60000], 
["IT", "Max", 60000]]}
```

However, when the GROUP BY is changed to e1.Id, then it works.

I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: So, what is the question?  Do you want to know why `e1.ID` in the `group by` makes it work?

Comment: @Yu -- I wonder if you have been able to make any progress w.r.t. this question?  Please consider upvote and/or accept the answers that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

**A quick guide to understand a complicated query**

Instead of telling you the answer directly, I suggest you do the following as 
an exercise.  This way you can understand not just this query, but will have
a methodology to understand future complex queries:

**Step 1: Indent your query**

You should indent your query to make it look like the following, which makes 
the structure of the query more apparent:

```
SELECT 
    d.Name AS Department
    , e.Name AS Employee
    , e.Salary
FROM 
    (
        SELECT                                      -- L1
            e1.Name
            , e1.Salary
            , e1.DepartmentId 
        FROM 
            Employee e1 
            JOIN Employee e2 
        WHERE 
            e1.DepartmentId = e2.DepartmentId 
            AND e1.Salary <= e2.Salary              -- L2
        -- GROUP BY e1.DepartmentId -- not working  
        GROUP BY e1.id              -- working      -- L3
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(e2.Salary)) <= 3      -- L4
    ) e
    JOIN Department d
        ON e.DepartmentId = d.Id
ORDER BY d.Name, e.Salary DESC
```

**Step 2: Try to understand from the innermost sub-query and expand your understanding outward**

In this case, the innermost sub-query is `e` (from `L1` to `L4`).  But
even this sub-query has multiple clauses that build up one on top of
another.  So I would first run this very simple query (it is a self-join,
as you said), from `L1` to `L2`, and what do you see?

```
        SELECT                                      -- L1
            e1.Name
            , e1.Salary
            , e1.DepartmentId 
        FROM 
            Employee e1 
            JOIN Employee e2 
        WHERE 
            e1.DepartmentId = e2.DepartmentId 
            AND e1.Salary <= e2.Salary              -- L2
```

Now when you see something (related to the effect of a self-join), then try
to add one more clause to it.  In this case try L3 (and the non-working
replacement)

```
        -- GROUP BY e1.DepartmentId -- not working  
        GROUP BY e1.id              -- working      -- L3
```

`GROUP BY` is for aggregation, it would be
odd to not see any aggregation function in the query, and then you 
may notice that there is an aggregation function (`COUNT(DISTINCT(e2.Salary))`)
to be added in the next step (for the `HAVING` clause), you can
add this function to one of the select expressions to see what
value it gets.  So, try this query now (i.e. with both L3 and L5 added):

```
        SELECT                                      -- L1
            e1.Name
            , e1.Salary
            , e1.DepartmentId 
            , COUNT(DISTINCT(e2.Salary))            -- L5
        FROM 
            Employee e1 
            JOIN Employee e2 
        WHERE 
            e1.DepartmentId = e2.DepartmentId 
            AND e1.Salary <= e2.Salary              -- L2
        GROUP BY e1.id              -- working      -- L3
```

What do you see?  Do you see the effect of the `GROUP BY`?

Now try adding one more clause -- `L4` -- and see if you understand
what it does

```
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(e2.Salary)) <= 3      -- L4
```

By now, you should understand what `e` does, now you put the whole
query together (the list from on the very top of this answer), and
do you now understand why the query work?

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I've used a solution similar to ROW_NUMBER over PARTITION used by other DBMS.

```
select @rn := case when @DepartmentId = DepartmentId then @rn + 1 else @rn := 1 end as rn,
       Id, Name, Salary, DName,
       @DepartmentId := DepartmentId as DepartmentId
from 
     (select @rn := 0 as rn) r,
     (select @DepartmentId := e.DepartmentId as DepartmentId, e.Name, e.Salary, e.Id, d.Name as DName
      from employ1 e
      inner join depart1  d on d.Id = e.DepartmentId
      order by e.DepartmentId, e.Salary desc) es;
```

This sentence returns the next values:

```
+----+----+-------+--------+-------+--------------+
| rn | Id |  Name | Salary | DName | DepartmentId |
+----+----+-------+--------+-------+--------------+
|  1 |  4 |  Max  |  90000 |   IT  |       1      |
+----+----+-------+--------+-------+--------------+
|  2 |  6 | Randy |  85000 |   IT  |       1      |
+----+----+-------+--------+-------+--------------+
|  3 |  1 |  Joe  |  70000 |   IT  |       1      |
+----+----+-------+--------+-------+--------------+
|  4 |  5 | Janet |  69000 |   IT  |       1      |
+----+----+-------+--------+-------+--------------+
|  1 |  2 | Henry |  80000 | Sales |       2      |
+----+----+-------+--------+-------+--------------+
|  2 |  3 |  Sam  |  60000 | Sales |       2      |
+----+----+-------+--------+-------+--------------+
```

As you can see, there is a rn column that reset it value for every department.

Then simply get the rows with a rn <= 3 to fetch the first 3 salaries.

```
select DName, Name, Salary
from (
        select @rn := case when @DepartmentId = DepartmentId then @rn + 1 else @rn := 1 end as rn,
               Id, Name, Salary, DName,
               @DepartmentId := DepartmentId as DepartmentId
        from 
             (select @rn := 0 as rn) r,
             (select @DepartmentId := e.DepartmentId as DepartmentId, e.Name, e.Salary, e.Id, d.Name as DName
              from employ1 e
              inner join depart1  d on d.Id = e.DepartmentId
              order by e.DepartmentId, e.Salary desc) es
    ) f
where rn <= 3;
```

This is the final result:

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| DName |  Name | Salary |
+-------+-------+--------+
|   IT  |  Max  |  90000 |
+-------+-------+--------+
|   IT  | Randy |  85000 |
+-------+-------+--------+
|   IT  |  Joe  |  70000 |
+-------+-------+--------+
| Sales | Henry |  80000 |
+-------+-------+--------+
| Sales |  Sam  |  60000 |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

Can check it here: http://rextester.com/MDK2215

Comment: What if salaries are tied?

Comment: @Strawberry you can add another variable `Salary`, and PARTITION BY Department,Salaty. You'll get two or more rows with the same ROW_NUMBER

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT    
        d.name  as "Department"                     
        ,e1.Name as "Employee"
        , e1.Salary as "Salary"

    FROM 
        Employee e1 
        JOIN Employee e2  JOIN Department d

    WHERE 
        e1.DepartmentId = e2.DepartmentId 
        AND e1.Salary <= e2.Salary  AND d.id = e2.DepartmentId


    GROUP BY d.name,e1.id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(e2.Salary)) <= 3
    ORDER BY d.name , salary DESC
```

Note**

Leetcode answer does not output the rows as promised.

This is the "expected" answer to match:

{"headers":["Department","Employee","Salary"],"values":[["IT","Max",90000],["IT","Joe",70000],["Sales","Henry",80000],["Sales","Sam",60000]]}

Answer (score 0):

Basic logic used -

1. Join two tables based on `DepartmentId` because that is the common column in both tables.
2. Assign rank to the salaries using `DENSE_RANK()` function `PARTITION BY DepartmentId` and `ORDER BY Salary DESC` because we want top three salaries of every department.
3. Get the details where dense rank value is <=3.

DENSE_RANK() function will assign the same rank to the salaries which have same value in a particular department.

```
SELECT details.Department "Department", details.Employee "Employee",
details.Salary "Salary", details.dense_rank AS DENSE_RANK FROM
(SELECT e.Name AS Employee, e.Salary AS Salary, e.DepartmentId, d.Name AS Department, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY e.DepartmentId ORDER BY e.Salary DESC) AS dense_rank
FROM Employee e, Department d
WHERE e.DepartmentId = d.Id) details
WHERE dense_rank <=3;
```

Output according to above query:

```
["Department", "Employee", "Salary", "DENSE_RANK"]
["IT",          "Max",      90000,     1]
["IT",          "Joe",      85000,     2] --same rank because same salary
["IT",          "Randy",    85000,     2] --same rank because same salary
["IT",          "Will",     70000,     3]
["Sales",       "Henry",    80000,     1]
["Sales",       "Sam",      60000,     2]
```

Check actual query at https://github.com/hetalrachh/leetcode/blob/master/Hard/DepartmentTop3Salaries.sql